# Selenium Firefox webdriver throws URLError

Tags: python, django, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm using the python version of selenium for some testing with django, but firefox webdriver is throwing an URLError exception when trying to start a new session. What I do is:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Update: then I do some testing, then I need to close it since the current test is done, but for the next one I need a fresh session, so I try to open a new one

```
browser.close()
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities()
browser.start_session(capabilities.FIREFOX)
```

but then it throws this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/projects/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 104, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/home/user/projects/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 153, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/user/projects/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 285, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/home/user/projects/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 326, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

The weird thing is that this same steps work perfectly fine with the Chrome webdriver.

Does anyone know why this could be caused?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: may I ask why you have to close it, before starting it up?

Comment: it's not like that, sorry if I didn't make myself clear.
I open it, then I do some test, then I need a fresh session to do another test so I call browser.start_session and it crashes.
I mean, I don't close it just because, I close it because I need a different session.
Is that any clearer? :)

Comment: Do you have SetUp, and TearDown set up in your test suite?

If so, that will handle the starting of new sessions and new browser instances. So each individual test will start and close the browser itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use start_session for that.
On the first line, you are creating a new instance of a local firefox browser. start_session is a method for the remote webdriver.
All you need is:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() #opens new Firefox browser locally
driver.quit() #kills the session
driver = webdriver.Firefox() #opens new Firefox browser locally
```

Since you are repeating code here, you should have something like this inside your test class

```
class Test(unittest.Testcase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
    def test_something(self):
        #do some magic test here
    def test_something_else(self):
        #do some other stuff
```

That way the browser will launch at the beginning of each test and close at the end of each test.